# Android: Error using calculator on CustomDialog

Tags: android, dialog, calculator

I have made a calculator for an activity and this works fine but I have tried to use this code into a customDialog in order to show this calculator but when I click in one of the buttons of the calculator the application crashes.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method ButtonClickHandler(View) in the activity class

```
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button5'
03-26 10:47:18.394: E/AndroidRuntime(7696):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3685)

03-26 10:47:18.394: E/AndroidRuntime(7696): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ButtonClickHandler [class android.view.View]
03-26 10:47:18.394: E/AndroidRuntime(7696):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
```

Here is some part of my code and the code that there is in the CustomDialog.

```
   calculadora.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    boolean clear_screen = true;                                
    boolean operator_state = false ;
    boolean insert_state = false;
    boolean last_click = false;
    float Operand1 = 0f;
    float Operand2 = 0f;
    float Answer = 0f;
    String Operator = "";
```

How could I solve this problem, taking into account that the problem is probably in "ButtonClickHandler"? Thank you

Comment: inside an inflated layout to set click listners you will have to find view by dialog.findViewById(xxx); something like that

Comment: how to use dialog.findViewById if I use ` switch(v.getId()){`

Comment: you can set on click listener for each buttons separately also (btn.setonclicklistner new view.oncliclistner...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did this in an activity and set the activity style to theme/dialog